# Golang juju/logger does not log the actual line in the log file

Tags: logging, go

I'm using juju/logger in my Golang application for logging. I have configured the logger to log error,info and trace
example:

```
filelog.go
-----------
func (obj fileLog) Infof(format string, args ...interface{}) {
    log.logger.Infof(format, args)
}
```

and when called, the logger file actually shows the line number of `filelog.go` where the logger is defined and not the actual location where the logger is called. I'm calling `filelog` as

```
log.Logger().Infof("Invalid data passed" + err.Error())
```

Is there any param to be configured to log the line number of the actual caller function? Please help.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536734/golang-find-filenames-and-line-numbers-that-prints-output-to-stdout

Comment: @Amd This applies for default logging. But for logging using juju/logger, i dont see any method that could provide this by default. So is there a way i could do?